# How to make checbox checked or uncheked in gridview editmode

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

i have made a gridview which has many columns and the editmode , some are text and dropdown list are are working perfect .

How can i assign value to a Checkbox to make it Checked or Unchecked?

The value against which i want to do is Yes / No.

So i am having trouble doing this.

My Gridview: Just pasting portion of it as its too big.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CUpdate">
    <ItemTemplate >
         <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CUpdate") %>' ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCupdate" Text='<%# Eval("CUpdate") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
    <ItemTemplate >
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>' ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkEmail"  runat="server">
            <%--HOW TO MAKE THIS CHECKED OR UNCHECKED ? when i have values Yes / NO--%>

        </asp:CheckBoxList>
     </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

> Update

If i make the above as :

```
 <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkEmail" selectedvalue='<%# Eval("Email") %>'  runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>

        </asp:CheckBoxList>
     </EditItemTemplate>
```

In this case i do get checkbox checked when there us Yes  , but in case on NO it wont run possible error as there is no value 'NO' to select in the checboxlist .Any solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CheckBoxList needs to have all the posible values like so..

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkEmail" selectedvalue='<%# Eval("Email") %>'  runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="No">No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Although i don't understand why you want to use a CheckBoxList instead of just 1 checkbox like so..

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkEmail" Checked = '<%# Eval("Email").ToString().Equals("yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) %>' />
```

Comment: okz, but i was thinking of one checkbox to show instead of showing both the Yes and NO one and selecting one.

Comment: That is what i was looking for but didn't knew how to convert the Yes to checkbox checked i will try this now :).